# How to send scroll_id to ElasticSearch with Curl

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I can't figure out how I should send scroll_id to ElasticSearch using Curl.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$url = "http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search?scroll=2m&_scroll_id=".$_POST["scroll_id"];
        $data = array(
            "_scroll_id" => $_POST["scroll_id"],
            "scroll_id" => $_POST["scroll_id"],
            "size" => 10, 
            "_source" => array(
                "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer",
                "Vrvirksomhed.elektroniskPost",
                "Vrvirksomhed.livsforloeb",
                "Vrvirksomhed.hjemmeside",
                "Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn",
                "Vrvirksomhed.hovedbranche",
                "Vrvirksomhed.penheder",
                "Vrvirksomhed.telefonnummer",
                "Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteBeliggenhedsadresse"
            ), 
            "query" => array (
                "bool" => array (
                    "must_not" => array (
                        "exists" => array (
                            "field" => "Vrvirksomhed.livsforloeb.periode.gyldigTil"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

The ElasticSearch returns the same 10 posts every time, so I think it doesn't get the scroll_id right.

Updated code after trying Val's suggestion. Using the setHosts I get a timeout after a long time. Leaving out the setHosts, I get the error saying that No alive nodes found in your cluster.

```
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';


    $username = "MY_USERNAME";
    $password = "MY_PASSWORD";
    
    $hosts = [
        'host' => 'distribution.virk.dk',
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'path'  => '/cvr-permanent',
        'port' => '80',
        'user' => $username,
        'pass' => $password
    ];

    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
    $params = [
    'scroll' => '30s',
    'size'   => 50,
    'type'   => '/cvr-permanent/virksomhed',
    'index'  => 'virksomhed',
    'body'   => [
        'query' => [
            'match_all' => new \stdClass()
        ]
    ]
    ];

    // Execute the search
    // The response will contain the first batch of documents
    // and a scroll_id
    $response = $client->search($params);

    // Now we loop until the scroll "cursors" are exhausted
    while (isset($response['hits']['hits']) && count($response['hits']['hits']) > 0) {

        // **
        // Do your work here, on the $response['hits']['hits'] array
        // **

        // When done, get the new scroll_id
        // You must always refresh your _scroll_id!  It can change sometimes
        $scroll_id = $response['_scroll_id'];

        // Execute a Scroll request and repeat
        $response = $client->scroll([
            'body' => [
                'scroll_id' => $scroll_id,  //...using our previously obtained _scroll_id
                'scroll'    => '30s'        // and the same timeout window
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps for using the scroll API.

In the first step you need to send the query and the duration of the scroll context.

In the second step, **you don't need to send the query again**, but only the scroll id you got from the previous scroll search.

You can find a full-blown example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/search_operations.html#_scrolling)

Comment: I have tried to follow the examples in your link. First I get "No alive nodes found in your cluster" and then I thought that I needed to fill in my username and password somewhere, så I added setHosts to the ClientBuilder line, but then I get a timeout error after a long time.

Comment: Maybe update your question with the new code you're trying

Comment: According to your first code snippet, I think you need to use port 80 and not 9200 as in your second snippet

Comment: Using port 80 doesn't give much change.

POST /cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m
{
 "_source":[
    "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer",
    "Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn",
    "Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteBeliggenhedsadresse"
  ],
  "query":{"match_all":{}},
  "size":200
}

Does that give any hint about what I should try?

Comment: I was talking about this: `'port' => '9200',` which should be `'port' => '80',`

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that I got right now. How should I understand Type and Index in the Params section?

Comment: `'index'   => 'cvr-permanent'` and `'type'   => 'virksomhed'`